# Producer Consumer problem - can't find the what's wrong

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

I am a beginner in Java trying **producer consumer** problem using **multi-threading** in Java.

#### Problems observed

- One thread isn't executing and I can't find why.
- There ain't any errors but output is not matching.
- The producer thread is running, still the consumer isn't.

#### The code

All classes are in one file with imports:

```java
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;
```

For readability I have split them here.

```java
class fun {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    int capacity=3;
    
    synchronized void produce()throws InterruptedException {
        int val=0;
        while(true) {
            while(list.size() == capacity) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer Produced : "+val);
            list.add(val);
            val++;
            notify();
        }
    }
    
    synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException { 
        while(true) {
            while(list.size() == 0) {
                wait();
            }
            int val;
            val = list.removeFirst();
            System.out.println("Consumer consumed-"+ val);
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

class `a` defines one thread:

```java
class a extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            fun obj=new fun();
            obj.produce();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

class `b` defines the other thread:

```java
class b extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        try {
            fun obj=new fun();
            obj.consume();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

class `pcp` contains the `main` method:

```java
class pcp {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws InterruptedException {
        a t1=new a();
        b t2=new b();
        t1.start();
        System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
C:\javaprogs>java pcp
true
true
Producer Produced : 0
Producer Produced : 1
Producer Produced : 2
```

I have been checking what's wrong in my Java code but I cant find any answer.

Comment: `a` and `b` are two different objects so the `wait`s and `notify`s are operating on each instance.  So the result is the consumer is waiting indefinitely - the producer is notifying but the consumer is not waiting on the producer but rather itself.  (they would have to notify the other object and they can continue to wait on themselves.)

Comment: I have reformatted your post completely. Please pay attention to code-formatting and indents. The easier to read, the easier to solve.

Comment: By the way, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are written in PascalCase.

Comment: @hc_dev oh thank you this is my first question so I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code/approach is that, you are using two different objects of class `fun` which ideally should have been a common shared resource among multiple threads.

> Inside class `b` you are instantiating new object of `fun` as
> shown below

```
try{    
    fun obj=new fun();
    obj.consume();
}
```

As instance of class `b` was never shared, below condition would always met

```
while(list.size() == 0) {
      wait();
}
```

and there would no other thread notifying to this waiting thread, because your producer thread is dealing with monitor of `a`; not `b`. This is causing your producer thread to continue only printing aforesaid stuff.

Now, to get rid of this issue, you can follow below steps

1. Consider declaring `fun` as a member of class `a` & `b` both
2. Provide a constructor in both `a` & `b` accepting `fun` type and initialise it with member variable
3. Inside `run()` method, try invoking `produce()` & `consume()` on `fun` member variable
4. Final step is, inside your main, create an object of `fun` and use it to create instances of `a` & `b`

Complete code with some modifications to your code is shown below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class pcp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        fun f = new fun();
        a t1=new a(f);
        b t2=new b(f);
        t1.start();
        System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
    }
}

class fun {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    int capacity = 3;

    synchronized void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        int val = 0;
        while (true) {
            while (list.size() == capacity) {
                wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Producer Produced : " + val);
            list.add(val);
            val++;
            notify();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            while (list.size() == 0) {
                wait();
            }
            int val;
            val = list.removeFirst();
            System.out.println("Consumer consumed-" + val);
            notify();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}

class a extends Thread {
    fun f;
    a(fun f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            f.produce();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

class b extends Thread {
    fun f;
    b(fun f) {
        this.f = f;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            f.consume();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Vishai, I reformatted the question's code for better readability. Some quotes or copied snippets in your answer might gotten out-of-sync now :(

Comment: Yeah, luckily no change in the code though :) Thanks to edit it for better readability @hc_dev

Comment: Thank You very much brother your explanation was very good , my problem is solved and I understood where I went wrong, since I created two objects to the fun class two linked lists are created and in turn the two threads doesn't  connected to each other for communication ,now the two objects created in threads are in turn connected to a single object in main class the threads are connected to a single instance of fun() function . Thankyou very much ...

Comment: @Srinivas, glad my answer was useful. Please accept the answer